# How to make FCM notification non-removable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

I want to make FCM notification that send to my flutter app non-removable ( the user can not clear it when click on clear button or slide the notification to the left).
I search for it but no answer about how to handle it with flutter and FCM notification.

Answer (score 1):

To make notification non-removable ... just make `ongoing: true` in `flutter_local_notifications` package

```
AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = new AndroidNotificationDetails("channelId",
    notificationModel.title, notificationModel.body,
    ongoing: true);
```